# How do I read JSON from a URL with F# JsonProvider

Tags: json, f#, type-providers

I was watching a Channel 9 video on "[Why you should use F#](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2017/T6064)" and was impressed at how easy it was to pull data off Wikipedia. For example, he showed the following code that listed out the different appearances of Dr Who...

```
[<Literal>]
let url = @"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who"
type DoctorWhoData = HtmlProvider<url>

let data = DoctorWhoData.GetSample()
let app = data.Tables.``Changes of appearance``.Rows
```

As he typed, he had Intellisense on that last line, which took the guesswork out of finding the data.

I recently had a requirement to pull some data from the Google Maps API. For example, the following URL pulls data for the UK postcode SW1A 1AA (Buckingham Palace in case any is interested!)...

[http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sw1a+1aa+uk](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sw1a%201aa%20uk)

Given that the data is just Json, I thought it should be equally easy to pull information from that using F#. However, I got stuck trying to get the latitude and longitude.

I started off with the following...

```
type GoogleData = JsonProvider<"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sw1a+1aa+uk">
```

...but then got stuck trying to extract the data. The json contains an array with one entry. That contains a `geometry` node, which contains a `location` node that holds the two values. In pseudo code, I would have expected to do something like this...

```
let lat = GoogleData.GetSample().[0].geometry.location.lat
```

...however, this didn't work. I tried it without GetSample(), but didn't get much further. Intellisense showed me things that didn't seem to match the Json at all...[image]

Anyone able to advise where I'm going wrong? How do I find the data? More to the point, how do I get Intellisense to help me? I managed to do this in C#, but it was very hit-and-miss as I had to use a dynamic object, so didn't get Intellisense. Based on what I saw in that video, I was hoping to get Intellisense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSON response contains 2 top level objects, `results` and `status`.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "SW1A 1AA",
               "short_name" : "SW1A 1AA",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
    //snip
    ],
    "status" : "OK"
}
```

The lat and long are under `results` so you need to follow that down from `.GetSample()`

```
let lat = GoogleData.GetSample().Results.[0].Geometry.Location.Lat
```

To use data other than the sample data use the `Load` function:

```
let honley = GoogleData.Load "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=honley+uk"
let honley_latlong = honley.Results.[0].Geometry.Location

//{
//  "lat": 53.602267,
//  "lng": -1.794173
//}
printfn "%A" honley_latlong
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't spot that status was also at the top level! Is there a neat way to get both lat and long in one go, such as `let (lat, lng) = ???` other than calling the whole line twice?

Comment: You could define a helper function `let ll2tp (ll: GoogleData.Northeast) = (ll.Lat, ll.Lng)` then `let (lat, lng) = honley.Results.[0].Geometry.Location |> ll2tp`

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I really gain much by doing it that way, but worth knowing. Thanks again for the help.